# Reading the content of an API (JSON)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Here's what I am requesting help for, I am currently working on a chatbot for discord as my first js project and it's going well so far. I want my bot to get a specific piece of info, e.g players, and then send it back to the user.

Here's the link the the API I am requesting the data from: https://minecraft-statistic.net/en/server/198.27.89.248_25629/json

How do I go about fetching a piece of data from the API?
All help is appreciated.

Comment: Please give more information

Comment: You forgot to ask your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few useful methods for you:
`XMLHttpRequest()`, `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()`

Use and change the following code to get what you need out of the response.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("get", "https://minecraft-statistic.net/en/server/198.27.89.248_25629/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
xhr.onload = function () {
  var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  // list all objects
  for (var key in response) {
    console.log(key, response[key]);
  }
  // list players
  console.log('players: ' + JSON.stringify(response['counter']['players']));
}
xhr.send();
```

For a quick test go to Firefox, press `Shift+F4`, paste and run this and check the console.

Answer (score 0):

load your property into an object from the JSON

so imagine this is your API's JSON

```
var json = {maxOnline: 8, currentPlayers: ["john", "steve", "bob"]}
```

to then get the 'currentPlayers' value you would use this syntax

```
var players = json["currentPlayers"]
console.log(players[0]); // outputs "john"
```